# How to store wine in hot city?

Tags: storage, wine

I'm planning to store wine bottles for several years, but I live in a hot city and don't have any cellar to use.

What other alternatives can I use to store the wine in a good environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How hot are we talking?
A cool closet on an inside wall of the house should be fine.

But I think the only real answer to this is a dedicated wine fridge with finer temp control.  One that you can set to a cellar type temp.  You don't want to store your red wine as cold as a normal fridge obviously.

Answer (score 3):

As brewchez suggests, there are a number of "wine cellars" on the market that are essentially mini-fridges that can run at cellar temp.  Another option, if you have the room, is to use a Johnson Controls thermostat with a full-size refrigerator as brewers often do for control of fermentation temperature. (here is one example: http://www.midwestsupplies.com/johnson-digital-temperature-controller.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could get a cheap table-top wine fridge.